# How to select only one dropdown from multiple dropdowns in a list with submit button enable /disable using jquery?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create multiple dropdowns in a table with a submit button which should allow to select only one dropdown option. I f the second dropdown is selected then it should pop a disallow message.

Note: am successful when I compare for same options in multiple dropdowns but unsuccesfull while comparing different options. So please sort out this.
I have tried in this url:
http://jsfiddle.net/dvtk974d/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#table1 tr').each(function() {
    $(this).find('select').change(function() {
      //alert($(this).val());
      $("#btSubmit").removeAttr("disabled");
      if ($(this).val() == 'action') {
        $("#btSubmit").prop('disabled', true);
      }
      if ($('#table1').find('select    option[value=' + $(this).val() + ']:selected').length > 1 && $(this).val() !== "action") {

        alert('option is already selected');
        $(this).val($(this).find("option:first").val());
      }
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3> Table 1</h3>

<table id="table1" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>select any action</td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option value="action">--Action--</option>
        <option value="one">One</option>
        <option value="two">Two</option>
        <option value="three">Three</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>select any action</td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option value="action">--Action--</option>
        <option value="one">One</option>
        <option value="two">Two</option>
        <option value="three">Three</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>select any action</td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option value="action">--Action--</option>
        <option value="one">One</option>
        <option value="two">Two</option>
        <option value="three">Three</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>select any action</td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option value="action">--Action--</option>
        <option value="one">One</option>
        <option value="two">Two</option>
        <option value="three">Three</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" title="Submit" name="submit" class="btn" id="btSubmit" disabled="disabled">
<br>
```

Comment: You mean out of 4 dropdown only one dropdown's option has to be selected like **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/dvtk974d/2/)**

Comment: No. It should alert irrespective of submit button. I mean other dropdown should not allow to select an option if a dropdown is selected.

Comment: that was just a demo!! So that's how you want it right??

Comment: Yes only one dropdown's    option has to be seelcted but not with the submit button click. It should alert when another dropdown option is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select all `select` elements, then exclude the current with `.not(this)` and disable them. You can re-enable them if the user selects "action" again. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ilpo/dvtk974d/3/

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to `alert` you can use this:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/dvtk974d/5/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var globalSelect=false;
    $('#table1 tr').each(function () {
        $(this).find('select').change(function () {
            //alert($(this).val());
            if(globalSelect)
            {
                if ($(this).val() == 'action') {// need to check here
                       $("#btSubmit").prop('disabled', true);
                       return;
                }
                alert('Option already selected');
                $(this).val($(this).find("option:first").val());
                return false;
            }
            $("#btSubmit").removeAttr("disabled");
            if ($(this).val() == 'action') {
                 $("#btSubmit").prop('disabled', true);
                 globalSelect=false;
            }
            else
            {
                globalSelect=true;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thankyou for the answer but its has some error when second time dropdown value changed i.e getting alert when selecting ---action--.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#table1 tr').each(function() {
    $(this).find('select').change(function() {
      //alert($(this).val());
      $("#btSubmit").removeAttr("disabled");
      if ($(this).val() == 'action') {
        $("#btSubmit").prop('disabled', true);
      }
      if ($('#table1').find('select    option[value=' + $(this).val() + ']:selected').length > 1 && $(this).val() !== "action") {

        alert('option is already selected');
        $(this).val($(this).find("option:first").val());
      }
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3> Table 1</h3>

<table id="table1" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>select any action</td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option value="action">--Action--</option>
        <option value="one">One</option>
        <option value="two">Two</option>
        <option value="three">Three</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>select any action</td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option value="action">--Action--</option>
        <option value="one">One</option>
        <option value="two">Two</option>
        <option value="three">Three</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>select any action</td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option value="action">--Action--</option>
        <option value="one">One</option>
        <option value="two">Two</option>
        <option value="three">Three</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>select any action</td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option value="action">--Action--</option>
        <option value="one">One</option>
        <option value="two">Two</option>
        <option value="three">Three</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" title="Submit" name="submit" class="btn" id="btSubmit" disabled="disabled">
<br>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).